# somewhat odd javascript code works in all major browsers, but fails with phantomjs/qunit

Tags: javascript, requirejs, phantomjs, qunit, jstestrunner

I work on an app with a javascript/html front-end and a back-end REST service.  I mostly work on the back end service, but I'm attempting to add javascript unit tests to the build.  I had someone help me with the javascript testing framework setup, using phantomjs, qunit, and jstestrunner, all referenced from Maven.

I wrote a trivial unit test for a module (we'll call it "data.daily.js") that begins like this:

```
Data.Daily = new Function();
Data.Daily.prototype = {
```

Just to be clear, this code runs every day in production, and appears to work fine in all major browsers (FF, IE, and Chrome).

The test looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({ shim: { 'data.daily': ['config'] } });
require(['data.daily'], function() {
    'use strict';
    module('data.daily');
    test('data.daily.test.initialize', function() {
        var dataDaily   = new Data.Daily();
        dataDaily.initialize(Config.AJAX_DAILY_DATA_BASE_URL, Config.MOCKDATA_AJAX_DAILY_DATA_BASE_URL);
        deepEqual(dataDaily.getData(), {}, "object is \"" + JSON.stringify(dataDaily.getData()) + "\", but it should be empty object");
    });
});
```

When I run this test, it fails like this:

```
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Data, source: http://localhost:9080/data.daily.js:5
  [data.daily] data.daily.test.initialize: failed: 1 passed: 0
  Died on test #1     at http://localhost:9080/js/qunit.js:425
at http://localhost:9080/js/data.daily.test.js:17
at http://localhost:9080/js/require.js:1682
at http://localhost:9080/js/require.js:983
at http://localhost:9080/js/require.js:1194
at http://localhost:9080/js/require.js:129
at http://localhost:9080/js/require.js:1237
at each (http://localhost:9080/js/require.js:58)
at http://localhost:9080/js/require.js:1238
at http://localhost:9080/js/require.js:1043
at http://localhost:9080/js/require.js:1224
at http://localhost:9080/js/require.js:882
at callGetModule (http://localhost:9080/js/require.js:1249)
at http://localhost:9080/js/require.js:1578
at http://localhost:9080/js/require.js:1703: Can't find variable: Data, source: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Data
```

The only way I can find to get this test working is to change "data.daily.js" in this way, adding a line before the existing lines:

```
var Data    = {};
Data.Daily = new Function();
Data.Daily.prototype = {
```

Now I have to say that this looks logical to me, but the fact remains that the existing code works fine in all the major browsers.  This code only started failing when referenced from the test.

Note that I also tried changing the test script instead, adding the "var Data = {}" line before the "var dataDaily = new Data.Daily()" line, but that had no effect.

So, can anyone explain what is going on here?  Why does the original code work if it fails in the test.  Is there something funky about how "require.js" works that makes this happen?  Why didn't the test work by adding the line in the test, instead of the CUT (code under test)?

Comment: The only way that can be working in any browser context is if the code comes after some *other* code that creates a global variable called "Data". If you don't declare a variable, and then try to dereference it with the `.` operator, you'll get an error, always.

Comment: Are there any other scripts being loaded in your production code which is not being loaded in your tests? As @Pointy pointed out, something has to be creating that `Data` global or it would fail.

Comment: Sigh.  I was going to say that I'd already searched the entire code base for references to "Data" and didn't find it.  However, I had just realized that I had only searched "*.js" files for this.  I finally found it in the "index.html".  I now at least understand that part.  What still isn't clear, however, is why I can't get the test to work by simply adding the "var Data = {}" line in the test script itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've managed to resolve this.

The assignment is actually present in the existing production code, I just didn't think to look in "*.html" files for it before.  When I didn't find it in "*.js" files, I thought something else was going on.

The reason it didn't work to put the line in the test script instead was because I was putting the line in the wrong place.  The error actually occurs at configuration time, not when the test itself is executed, so the assignment had to be before the "requirejs.config()" call.  Now the test works, without having to modify the CUT.